# VIDIOC_STREAMON : broken pipe on Ubuntu VMWare

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, webcam, v4l2, vmware-player

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 installed on VMWare Player 6.0 on Windows 7.
I have tested my OpenCV application on Ubuntu host but on VM I'm unable to get the webcam running (HD Pro Webcam C920). I get a `VIDIOC_STREAMON: Broken pipe` error. I tried `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4lv4l1compat.so ./myApp` but I get `ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/libv4lv4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.` Please guide me to solve this problem.